# Windows will appear via shortcut but not execute in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I have a strange set of symptoms on my new Macbook Pro I have not seen before.

- **Model:** Macbook Pro 15 inch, late 2016
- **OS:** Sierra 10.12.1

I was able to have windows appear, but I was not able to act on them (i.e. close them, click buttons, etc.)

- **<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>**: Shows app switcher, but would never switch.
- **<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>**: Shows force quit interface, but could not close or click buttons.
- **Triple tap <kbd>Touch ID</kbd>**: accessibility options overlay appears, can not close.
- **Siri button**: Siri appears. Used to turn off Bluetooth (in case stuck mouse).

If anybody has likely culprits, please let me know.

## Update: I no longer have this issue.

My guess is apple worked out kinks in the new software, or I had a unique unusual combination of causes.

Comment: Brand new OS, or migration from an older one? I'm thinking you imported 3rd party structures that are not agreeing with Sierra. Check all older apps/utilities for possible updates.

Comment: @Tetsujin brand new, no migration. Got to fight those cobwebs!